# How to build a command line interface in java for an existing web based application

Tags: java, command-line, ejb, command-prompt

I have created a web based application using JSP and Servlets and the application uses an SQL Server DB as its backend.

The architecture is like this:

1. I have all my business logic in a jar file
2. I have created my views using JSPs and am using servlets to interact with my business logic jar
3. The jar connects to the database to persist and hydrate information, which is relayed to the JSP by my servlets.

My web application runs on a remote Tomcat server.

Now, I have been given a new requirement. I have to create a command line interface, where I should be able to specify a list of commands and hit enter (or alternatively, create a set of commands and save it in a .bat file or something, and run it), so that my application performs the necessary actions. Basically, I have to create a command line interface, which can be used along with the GUI i already have (JSPs).

I am totally new to this. Can anyone throw light on where and how I can start?

Any little help is greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

This is what my web application does. User can see a list of test scripts (written in Selenium WebDriver). He can choose script(s), choose a host on where to run them from, and click "Run", and the test executes on the said machines.

Now, I want a command line interface, which will eliminate the need for the GUI. Let's say, I simply want the user to be able to type a command like "execute My_Script_1", and the script should be executed.

The test scripts, the selenium drivers, everything reside on the App server.

My command line interface should be able to work on Windows command prompt.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use python for creating CLI. So far i have used python is easy to implement CLI.

Comment: Thank you @Shriram, but I am forced to use Java. Do you have any idea how I can do it in Java?

Comment: I won't downvote because your question is very well-formed, but you will have to be more specific about what this CLI has to accomplish, because as it is now it's kind of broad. What platform will it be using (Linux terminal? Windows cmd? Custom-made Java prompt?), what will those commands control?

Answer (score 1):

You say you have your business logic in a JAR.

Why not starting another project with this JAR as a dependency and build it as an executable jar ? 
Then simply use System.in and System.out to interact with the user.

**EDIT** :

So your application is hosted. Do you have an API like REST or SOAP or any other ?

Then you can build a client reading a string that the user has written, parsing it and calling the right service in your API.

Comment: That is what I set out to build, @Thomas. But I'm stuck up here. See let's say, when I run command 1, my application creates an  object of class, say MyClass. Now if user runs command 2, if command 2 needs to use the object that was created by command 1, how do I access it. Sorry if my question is basic, but that's how much I know ..

Comment: Ok so you need to tell us a bit more. Where is your application hosted ? Do you have a shared instance that everybody should access ? Or can you package an instance of the full application in the executable jar ?

Comment: As of now, I have hosted teh application on a Tomcat container on a remote server. I could also package an instance of the full application as you said in the executable jar. But, in the latter case, how do I retain my objects as I specified earlier?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Spring?
Can you specify, what exactly your CLI should do?

You may do, what Thomas said.
You also may use template engines like Velocity.. To form your output.
Use some kind of JavaCurses-like library to make your output... Look well.

Specifying commands...
Hm.. think about your business logic what exactly you are showing to user.
Remember webapp ui is webapp ui. Console ui is different. And user expects different behaviour

So commands like

```
show goods category="for kids"
```

Will be great.
Also don't forget about different help commands
yourJarName.jar --help / -h and etc

If your are want to write application with interactive mode... think about help command there.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

- Create a client-side CLI that generates the same data your server
  receives. In other words, you don't modify your server code, and you create a
  client-side CLI module (with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example) that parses the command lines and sends
  exactly the same thing your actual GUI sends.
- Set up a text area in your web app (decorated as a CLI) that reacts
  on each *Enter* key pressed, and sends the line(s) to your server. On
  your server, you can create a utility class (say CLIParser.java for
  instance), and use [Args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) to parse the received command,
  validate it and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Primefaces terminal? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/terminal.xhtml

Answer (score -1):

You data structure looks simple enough. Also you mentioned you designed your application the way the business logic is separated from the front end.

In this case you may consider exposing your business logic as a REST based WebService. It should not be that hard since you have layered structure in your application.

Looks like a few methods:

- list scripts - returns a list of available scripts list hosts
- returns a list of available hosts run script(scriptName, hostAddress)
- runs script scriptName on a host with on address hostAddress possibly returns the results if your application supports this

All three look like a good candidates for GET methods.

You may consider [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) or [Resteasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) or another framework.

You can find plenty tutorials for both of them. Take a look for example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/).

From your command line application you can make calls to your web service in different ways. Just because I used to work with Jersey JAX-RS implementation most of the time, I found use of [Jersey client(the latest stable version)](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/user-guide.html) the most convenient. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/) you can find a short tutorial how you can do it from your command line application with Jersey client. JBoss also has a [client API](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) as a part of their framework(also fully certified JAX-RS implementation). You may even decide not to use any client API and do all the work manually utilizing HttpURLConnection, but I would not recommend. There is no big difference in using client API or do all the work manually with HttpURLConnection for the simple service, but you never know when your application becomes not that simple because of new requirements your client could not think of at the beginning.

Hope that helps